# Evaluating 8-bit binary values with the & operator

Tags: c, binary, operators, bit

I am having trouble evaluating 8-bit unsigned binary values with the & operator.

For example: would 0b11110101 & 0b11111100 = 0b01001010.

If not, then what would be the correct binary value?

Comment: No, `0b11110101 & 0b11111100 = 0b11110100`

Comment: Each bit in the result is `1` if the corresponding bits in both inputs are `1`. Otherwise it's `0`.

Comment: General rule: seeing each correspinding bits, the result bit is 1 if both of input bits are 1 and the result bit is 0 otherwise.

Comment: There is documentation easily available that explains what the operators does. Have you read them before posting?

Comment: @Big Mike from Laos Could you explain how you obtained this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(a) 0b11110101 &
(b) 0b11111100 =
----------------
    0b11110100
----------------
```

This is an `AND` operation, and both inputs (a) ***and*** (b) must be logical 1

[Boolean algebra basics](https://www.electrical4u.com/boolean-algebra-theorems-and-laws-of-boolean-algebra/)